# Can't run functions in .then() Axios React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios

I have a webpage where I fetch the data with async axios and then make calculations with them.

Here is the code snippet:

```
const FetchData = async () =>{
    console.log("FETCH CALLED");
    await Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/stock/getquote/${props.API}`)
          .then(resp => {
            setStockData(resp.data);
            calculateTrend();
            calculateTrendDirection();
          })
  }
```

Here, I get the error at calculateTrend() function. My question is, that this .then() should run when the response has arrived, but it seems that it runs before. Because both calculateTrend and calculateTrendDirection works with this fetched data

Edit: The error I am getting is Cannot read property 'previousClosePrice' of undefined. I am sure this exist in the object so mispelling is not a problem

Edit2: I edited my Component according to your solutions and one happens to work, the only thing is that the fetching gets to an infinite loop and fetches multiple times a second. My suspect is the dependencies in useEffect, but I am not sure what to set there.

Here is my full component:

```
function StockCard(props) {
  const [FetchInterval, setFetchInterval] = useState(300000);
  const [StockData, setStockData] = useState({});
  const [TrendDirection, setTrendDirection] = useState(0);
  const [Trend, setTrend] = useState(0);

  const FetchData = async () =>{
    console.log("FETCH CALLED");
    const resp = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/stock/getquote/${props.API}`)
      setStockData(resp.data);
  }

  const calculateTrendDirection = () => {
    console.log(StockData.lastPrice);
    if(StockData.lastPrice.currentPrice >  StockData.lastPrice.previousClosePrice){
      setTrendDirection(1);
    } else if (StockData.lastPrice.currentPrice <  StockData.lastPrice.previousClosePrice){
      setTrendDirection(-1);
    } else {
      setTrendDirection(0);
    }
  }

  const calculateTrend = () => {
    console.log(StockData.lastPrice);
    var result =  100 * Math.abs( ( StockData.lastPrice.previousClosePrice - StockData.lastPrice.currentPrice ) / ( (StockData.lastPrice.previousClosePrice + StockData.lastPrice.currentPrice)/2 ) );

    setTrend(result.toFixed(2));
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    FetchData();

    if(StockData.lastPrice){
      console.log("LÉTEZIK A LAST PRICE")
      calculateTrend();
      calculateTrendDirection();
    }
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      FetchData();
    }, FetchInterval)

    return() => clearInterval(interval);

  },[StockData, FetchData, FetchInterval, calculateTrend, calculateTrendDirection]);

  




    return(
        <div>
        <CryptoCard
          currencyName={StockData.lastPrice? StockData.name : "Name"}
          currencyPrice={StockData.lastPrice? `$ ${StockData.lastPrice.currentPrice}` : 0}
          icon={<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bitcoin.svg/2000px-Bitcoin.svg.png"/>}
          currencyShortName={StockData.lastPrice? StockData.symbol : "Symbol"}
          trend={StockData.lastPrice? `${Trend} %` : 0}
          trendDirection={StockData.lastPrice? TrendDirection : 0} 
          chartData={[9200, 5720, 8100, 6734, 7054, 7832, 6421, 7383, 8697, 8850]}
        />
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Looks like your `setStockData` does not set the state before the data is available. Add `useEffect` and call both functions once the data is available, or add the data as a param to both functions.

Comment: Please check my edit # 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `then` block is called only after the promise is fulfilled, so the data is available at that point.

From what I can see, the problem is `setStockData` tries to set the `stockData` state variable with the response, but `calculateTrend` and `calculateTrendDirection` are called before the state is set because updating state values is batched.

There are several solutions to the problem.

**Solution 1**:

You can call the two functions after the state is set:

```
setStockData(resp.data, () => {
  calculateTrend();
  calculateTrendDirection();
});
```

**Solution 2**:

You can use `useEffect` to call the functions again after the state is updated:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (stockData) { // or whatever validation needed
    calculateTrend();
    calculateTrendDirection();
  }
}, [stockData]);
```

**Solution 3**:

You can pass the parameters to the method:

```
calculateTrend(resp.data);
calculateTrendDirection(resp.data);
```

The best option? I think #2, because it also makes sure that the trend and trend direction are re-calculated whenever stock data is updated (from whatever other causes).

Comment: I went with solution 2, but still got the same error at the same place

Comment: That's probably because you didn't do the proper validation. Do something like `if (stockData.id)` or whatever mandatory field that should be available after you get the response.

Comment: You can have multiple `useEffect`s, so don't combine everything into one large `useEffect` and instead, add my code for strictly re-calculating the trends, and for others, use your current `useEffect`.

Comment: And what should I include in the dependencies section of useEffect?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but the dependencies should be what it actually depends on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in `calculateTrend` you are using the data which `setStockData` sets to the state, if that is the case

`setState` is not happening right after you call the `setState`, if you want something to execute after correctly update the State then should look at something like this

```
setStockData(resp.data, () => {
    calculateTrend();// this will call once the state gets changed
});
```

or you could use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    calculateTrend(); // this will call every time when stockData gets changed
}, [stockData])
```

Comment: This is my useEffect() now, but it still says to cancel every asnyc func in useEffect(and I have no idea how to do that).

```
useEffect(() => {
    FetchData();

    calculateTrend();
    calculateTrendDirection();
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      FetchData();
    }, FetchInterval)

    return() => clearInterval(interval);

  }, [FetchInterval, StockData]);
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you actually need, can you please add your component and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stockData inside calculateTrend function and setStockData is an async function, move calculateTrend function to useEffect using stockData as dependency, so every time stockData is updated, calculateTrend and  calculateTrendDirection will be called:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
     FetchData();
  }, FetchInterval);

  return() => clearInterval(interval);
}, [FetchInterval]);


useEffect(() => {
   if(StockData.lastPrice){
     console.log("LÉTEZIK A LAST PRICE")
     calculateTrend();
     calculateTrendDirection();
   }
}, [StockData]);

const FetchData = async () =>{
    console.log("FETCH CALLED");
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/stock/getquote/${props.API}`);
    setStockData(resp.data);
}
```

Comment: You can define multiple useEffect.

Comment: It still runs forever :(

Comment: I think there is a dependency that is causing many re renders ,try to remove one by one until you see what is causing the problem. Also check if interval function is part of the problem.